# Units of slope output

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, slope, terrain

I am calculating the slope from the DGM file which is of 1m spatial resolution.

The default CRS is ETRS89 33N 25833 for that particular piece of land in Germany, kustriner vorland.

In what units are the output files?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: whatever the metadata says the data is measured in, probably metres

Comment: THEN DO I HAVE TO REPROJECT THE RASTER TO LAT/LONG & THEN TRY SLOPE?

Comment: please don't SHOUT, no your horizontal data is already in metres so it should work just fine

Comment: Per official [QGIS documentation on the slope-tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasterterrainanalysis.html?highlight=slope#slope), the slope is given in degree. The GDAL-tool with the same name allows you to choose either degree or percent as unit of slope.